# Why is my second monitor doing this?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

so I've had this setup for like, half a year now, and it just now started doing this

[image]
 as you can see, my second monitor is pretty old but after i reformatted my computer, it started having this black box on the side, and i have tried all the resolutions to try and fix it but it just wont go full screen!

Comment: -1 What on earth is pictured there. A bunny rabbit presumably not on a screen but a puppet.  A bit of paper or beam of light, presumably not on/from the screen. I can hardly see the borders of the screen to the right. And then to the right of the screen on the right you have a rectangular screen that may just be a reflection or something. It looks like a stunt from a magic show. Pulling a rabbit out of a monitor whose borders are almost invisible.. while the projection of a little rectangular screen appears.  Very poorly communicated.

Comment: lol its a majestic cat behind a mountain looking majestically at my other monitor xD

Answer (score 1):

You can probably fix this by using the buttons (and On Screen Display) of the monitor, to change the vertical and horizontal position of the image.

It might also be possible to just fix it by using the "auto" mode.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Display Settings (you can search for "display settings" from the Start Menu, or right-clicking on the desktop, then choose Personalize)
2. Check if all monitors are detected (you should have two)
3. (Optional) Pick the monitor that you want to be the default display by ticking the `Make this my main display` option
4. Re-arrange the monitors accordingly by dragging them
5. Set the behaviour on how Windows should treat multiple displays from the `Multiple display` drop-down option

[image]

Comment: ah snap dude, thanks alot, that fixed it! lots of love!